# How do I detect whether changes in nano were discarded or saved?

Tags: bash, scripting, nano

I am currently writing a small setup script for a Linux application that needs the user to edit a configuration file before the application is started. I've chosen to make the script simply open the configuration file in Nano, and resume the script afterwards. I do, however, need to detect whether the user saved the changes (to then continue starting the application), or whether he discarded them (which would indicate the user doesn't want to continue).

I have already checked whether this is possible with the returned exit code from Nano, and it apparently isn't - it always returns 0 even if the changes were discarded. Is there another way to figure out whether the file was changed and saved, or will I have to do this in an entirely different way?

Comment: Make a tmp copy of the file and have the user edit that instead of the original.  When they exit `nano`, `diff` the tmp file with the default to see if it was changed.

Comment: You shouldn't default to nano, it is better to use whatever `$EDITOR` is set to.

Comment: Do you want to check whether the user changed the file or whether he saved the file?  I don't know `nano`, but I know that, in `vi`, you can type `:wq` and it will save (i.e., rewrite) the file even if you made no changes.  The accepted answer will consider that to be a positive result (yes, the user saved the file).  The temp copy approach (suggested in a comment, above) recognizes only actual edits (changes) to the file.  If you're concerned about the space requirements of making a copy, just hash it before and after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [stat](http://man.cx/stat) command to check the file's modification time before and after `nano`.  Something like:

```
oldtime=`stat -c %Y "$filename"`
nano "$filename"

if [[ `stat -c %Y "$filename"` -gt $oldtime ]] ; then
  echo $filename has been modified
fi
```

Of course, this won't detect whether `nano` modified the file, or some other program did, but that could be considered a feature.  (You can use some other program to edit the file, and then exit `nano` without saving.)

Answer (score 0):

I was recently trying to do something similar, I eventually used a modification of @cjm's approach.

First of all, under Darwin, I used `stat -f %m` to get the time (in seconds) since the file was modified.

This works well, but there is a small chance that the user will save and exit the editor in the same second as a modification made by your script. To solve this, I manually bump the modified time of the file by one second using touch.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "some text" > myfile.txt
touch -A -01 myfile.txt
oldtime=`stat -f %m myfile.txt`
vi myfile.txt
if [[ `stat -f %m myfile.txt` -gt $oldtime ]] ; then
    echo "file was edited"
fi
```

Comment: The `-A` option to `touch` is not universally available.  A simpler way of getting a similar effect would be to `sleep 1` before invoking the editor.

Comment: Granted simpler, but I cringe at the thought of making the user wait a second before popping the editor open.